# Часть кода не работает

Tags: python

мне нужен такой результат:

```
            1 25/06/2022, 10:09:35{'phone': '998901577071', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '4454'}
            2 25/06/2022, 10:09:58{'phone': '998901577071', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '4457'}
            3 25/06/2022, 10:14:18{'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
            4 25/06/2022, 10:17:32{'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
```

Код

```
        data={'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
    
    
                with open ('log.txt', 'a+') as log:
                        line_num=0
                        now1=datetime.now()
                        log.write(str(line_num))
                        log.write(' ')
                        log.write(now1.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
                        log.write(str(data))
                        log.write('\n')
```

Получается так:

```
1 25/06/2022, 10:09:35{'phone': '998901577071', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '4454'}
1 25/06/2022, 10:09:58{'phone': '998901577071', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '4457'}
1 25/06/2022, 10:14:18{'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
1 25/06/2022, 10:17:32{'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
0 25/06/2022, 10:42:34{'phone': '998902930528', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '2638'}
0 25/06/2022, 10:44:09{'phone': '998900041004', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '3768'}
1 25/06/2022, 10:46:20{'phone': '998901296003', 'fio': 'Its me', 'code': '1119'}
```

Comment: А какой результат у вас выдаётся вместо ожидаемого? Может какая-то ошибка?

Comment: обновил код., проверьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Опиши словами разницу в том что получается, и в том, что должно быть. И добавь кода, приведённый код не может выдать такой результат, который якобы выдаёт

Comment: у вас проблема с последовательными номерами? не надо их в файл писать. Они не несут никакой информации. Но если нужны, добавляйте при выводе результата

Comment: да, совершенно верно. Но как , не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `count` возвращает объект, которые возвращает последовательные целые числа при каждом вызове `next`. Создайте один такой объект и используйте его для нумерации строк в логе.

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    c = start
    while True:
        yield c
        c += step


c = count(1)
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
```

**P.S.** Если что мопед не мой, я только разместил объявление: [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools


c = itertools.count(1)
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
print(next(c))
```